# running unity webgl file on ASP.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, unity-webgl

I tried making a webgl game. When I "build and run" it, it works perfectly fine but when I import it in ASP.net core mvc, it says:

> Unexpected token '<'

what I tried:

1. removing compression in unity
2. using other versions of unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this error message:`Unexpected token '<'`.

Check whether the imported JS file path is correct.

If the import path is correct, there may be a problem with the JavaScript method, and then check whether the method uses an undefined function or the like.